# ASP to PHP MS SQL Connection Error

Tags: php, sql-server, asp-classic, database-connection

So I am currently going through the process of migrating alot of projects from old asp (VBScript) to PHP5.

This project has to connect to a remote MS SQL DB.

The old ASP connection string was:

```
<%
 Set MyConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
MyConn.Open "driver={SQL      
Server};server=**.***.***.***;UID=username;PASSWORD=password;DATABASE=DBname"
session.lcid=2057
%>
```

My new PHP connection string is:

```
<?

$myServer = "**.***.***.***";
$myUser = "username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "DBname";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

?>
```

However although it tries it fails every time and displays this error:

Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: **.**.**.** in (filepath) on line 8
Couldn't connect to SQL Server on **.**.***.***

I sort of think it might be to do with not defining a driver, but after searching for a while I can't seem to find a definitive answer as to which or what drive, if one is needed to use. Anyone see where im going wrong? I have checked and double checked the login information and it is correct.

Comment: Have you tested that the server running PHP can actually see the server running SQL?

Comment: No, what is the best way to go about this? Will see if I can search for that answer myself of course, just if you know off the top of your head. :)

Comment: The easiest way is to just just log on to the PHP server and see if you can ping the SQL servers IP. Also it's worth making sure that the SQL server hasn't got a firewall blocking it's ports. I think (you'll want to check) that the MSSQL Server port is 1433.

Comment: This actually led me to finding a problem with the current set up of the server. If you put this in a answer ill accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to **JerryF** I tried pinging my SQL server from my PHP server with no success. It turned out that we needed to update our servers and ensure the correct PHP dlls were being used. Once we didthis the code worked fine and everything ran smoothly.

Just an answer to resolve the question. With credit to **JerryF**